# Play sound in a specific sound card (Adobe AIR)

Tags: audio, apache-flex, actionscript, air, soundcard

I am writing a desktop application using Adobe AIR. One of its functions is to play mp3 files, and the requirement is that the client have the option to select which sound card, if more than one, will play the song.

Now, I know that I can assign a different SoundChannel object to every Sound.play() call and control each SounChannel object separately, e.g. setting the volume of each sound, but the combined result will play on the default sound card.

Unfortunately, from what I have managed to find out until now, there is no such possibility in AIR, not even the ability to enumerate the available sound devices.

I want to ask if, hopefully, I missed something and this is not so, or if someone knows of a workaround to achieve the desired effect.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this app for Windows? You could run some command line tool like [**NirCMD**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) via `nativeProcess`. It would be all transparent to the end-user (switching appears to happen from your own program). Before I expand, let me know if this is an acceptable option or ask for any clarification...

Comment: VC.One thank you for your reply. Yes, this app is for Windows. Please,  do expand, this sounds very interesting :-)

Comment: _"there is no such possibility in AIR, not even the ability to enumerate the available sound devices"_ did you explore the `nativeProcess`? I was hoping when you read up on it, you'd see possibility to use a commandline tool and receive data from or send commands to it via **std in/out** functions. NirCMD was one example but there is also simpler [**Audio EPC**](https://github.com/DanStevens/AudioEndPointController). Did you find one you need help with?